# Finding and replacing utf characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii, utf

If I was processing text, how would I know if these symbols are inside the text? Because I want to remove them. I'm new to PHP, I have no idea how to search for these.

```
▲ - U+25B2 BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
▼ - U+25BC BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
▴ - U+25B4 SMALL BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE
▾ - U+25BE SMALL BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE
```

Thank you,

PS: I am not sure that they are UTF, they might also be ASCII.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Trivially, `str.replace(/[▲▼▴▾]/g, '')`.

Or, if for some weird reason your JavaScript is not Unicode, you could write the equivalent `str.replace(/[\u25b2\u25bc\u25b4\u25be]/g, '')`.

Comment: How would I put the triangles in VI for example?

Comment: Copy-paste? Or `<Ctrl-V>u25b2` (at least Vim; I haven't worked with plain VI in decades).

Comment: Would this work on php? (besides the str.replace of course) ?

Comment: `preg_replace("/[▲▼▴▾]/", "", $str)`.